# Uninstall (or hide) Calendar, Mail, Maps, and People

Tags: windows-10

How can I install (or hide) the following Windows 10 Desktop Apps: Calendar, Mail, Maps, People?

I use the Google versions of all of these apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trusted modern apps in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/950873/removing-trusted-modern-apps-in-windows-10), [How do you forcefully remove apps in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10)