# Can I turn off or disable Store App from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I need to turn off or disable the **Store** App from Windows 10 as I used to in Windows 8.1 using GPO (gpedit.msc) in local computers but Win10 doesn't have that option anymore

Computer Configuration => Policies => Administrative Templates 
=> Windows Components => **Store(Nop in Win10)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9514c7a6-991b-48b0-95ab-33edfc029c52/windows-10-enterprise-disable-store-feature?forum=win10itprogeneral:

The WinStoreUI.ADMX & WinStoreUI.ADML, are missing from the Win10 template download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257

But since the settings are no different from the Win8.1u1 templates, you can grab the missing files from the Win8.1u1 download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43413

Comment: I installed this, and still can't access gpedit.msc (there is no such app).

What should I do?

Comment: @ripper234 - Windows 10 Home does not have gpedit.msc, which means you would have to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional, if you wanted to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

And this policy has apparently been rendered useless except on Windows 10 Enterprise/Education

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135657

guess the only other option is to uninstall the store appx:

from powershell:

to remove the **existing** Appx for the currently logged-in user:

```
Get-AppxPackage *WindowsStore* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

to remove the **provisioned** Appx (only applies to future users without a current profile):

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object {$_.PackageName -like "*WindowsStore*"} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

n.b. this option should only be used if the full ramifications of removing provisioned packages are understood.. Once a **provisioned** app is removed, it is hard to get back

more info: [How do you forcefully remove apps in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10) and [Restore Microsoft Store application in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10)

Here's another solution: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-store-applications-manager

found some more policies that are likely soon to be enabled only in enterprise: https://dirteam.com/sander/2015/05/05/knowledgebase-important-issues-in-windows-server-2016-technical-preview-2-release-notes/

> In this release, the following Group Policy Objects are not implemented:
>
> Specify intranet Microsoft update service location
>
> Do not connect to any Windows Update Internet locations
>
> Allow signed updates from an intranet Microsoft update service

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer since the question was asked before Version 1511 was released.  so the other option how?, not that I care, but saying there is one then not saying how is annoying

Comment: changed to 'answer'

Comment: found some more policies that are likely soon to be enabled only in enterprise:

Group Policy
In this release, the following Group Policy Objects are not implemented:
Specify intranet Microsoft update service location
Do not connect to any Windows Update Internet locations
Allow signed updates from an intranet Microsoft update service
https://dirteam.com/sander/2015/05/05/knowledgebase-important-issues-in-windows-server-2016-technical-preview-2-release-notes/

Comment: An answer should contain all relevant information you feel is important.  Comments are not guaranteed to exist tomorrow.  For instance my previous comment is obsolete, so if flagged and brought to the attention of a moderator, all comments likely would be deleted

Comment: Didn't think it was relevant to the answer.. But thought it was useful info.  Added to answer anyway at your suggestion

Comment: Warning to users, when updating the computer, once Store is removed from provisioning, with fresh install it will be missing from apps folder! See [here](https://superuser.com/a/1449292/900431) to get Store back.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake these are the files you actually need in the Central Store from the Windows 8.1 ADMX templates don't add the locationprovider files (yes you will need both the admx and adml files when the store will available along with some other group policy settings that were removed from the win 10 package:

[image]