# How do I remove Candy Crush Saga from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

Windows 10 comes with "Candy Crush Saga" preinstalled, but I do not want it on my system. How do I remove it?

Comment: CCS is not part of the default installation of Windows 10; that it came automatically on your machine could be due to OEM bloatware or the Windows Store automatically installing apps previously purchased on your Microsoft Account.

Comment: @GhillieDhu that is not correct for upgrades. Please see https://blogs.microsoft.com/firehose/2015/05/14/tasty-treats-incoming-to-windows-10-with-candy-crush-saga/

Comment: I actually had to install it, because surprise, I like it, and it was not automatically preinstalled.

Comment: I stand corrected. I have three W10 machines, two were upgraded pre-launch (1 Enterprise & 1 Pro) & the third had a clean install from the MSDN subscriber download; none of them have CCS.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/a/942419/49695

Comment: @GhillieDhu it's possible that the Pro/Enterprise flavors and/or pre-launch upgrades do not install it. Dunno about clean installs.

Comment: @Devin None of my PCs or my friends' PCs have Candy Crush Saga preinstalled after upgrade

Comment: Hmm... http://neurogadget.com/2015/08/16/windows-10-will-install-candy-crush-saga-automatically/12682

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what's the difference with this and having minesweeper preinstalled for example? These comments about choosing mac over pc for this reason made me interested.

Comment: When I bought an iBook running OS X 10.3, it came with [Marble Blast Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble_Blast_Gold) pre-installed. Windows 95 came wish [Hover!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hover!)… they were really great games, and nobody complained AFAIK. Ok, I dislike dearly Candy Crush too, and I definitely hate King, but… still this isn't very different. Pre-installed games are actually a nice thing. As long as you can uninstall and re-install them, of course.

Comment: Minesweeper and Solitaire (and Hover! for that matter) are "in-house" games; Candy Crush Saga is a third party game -- that's the key difference to me at least. Add in the fact that I dislike and do not trust its publisher, and I am definitely not pleased with this being given to me as a "bonus".

Comment: @DoktorJ Well as I checked out pinball game which was distributed I believe with Windows XP was also developed by third party company called Cinematronics. Makes me wonder how all the people still hasn't moved to mac since those days long gone. Not that I don't admire your valiant effort to free precious 50 MB of course :)

Comment: The games keep *reinstalling automatically*, even though I have uninstalled them before, and they are always placed at the top of the start menu. This is nothing like minesweeper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you forcefully remove apps in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Windows Store and other Universal Apps in Windows 10 Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1097128/how-to-remove-windows-store-and-other-universal-apps-in-windows-10-pro)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I was able to uninstall simply by right-clicking on the app in the Start Menu and selecting uninstall.

Typing `Get-AppxPackage -Name king.com.CandyCrushSaga` into PowerShell confirmed it is completely gone from the system, not just from the start menu.

Comment: I will be upgrading my desktop shortly (if it lets me; I have my "Users" folder in a custom location, which apparently thwarted an upgrade to 8.1) as well as my fiancee's desktop. I will test this method on both of those -- if it works this is definitely a better answer!

Comment: And how do you prevent Microsoft from reinstalling it for you because it knows better? Is there an appxpackage i can remove for "microsoft autonomously installing pay to win garbage trash, wasting my bandwidth and insulting my intelligence"?

Comment: When using https://nirsoft.net/utils/url_protocol_view.html you see that even after uninstalling ... bubblewithsaga3 and candycrushsodasaga are still installed as ... url protocol handlers.

Comment: See @dark-daskin's answer below for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 36):

Since Candy Crush Saga is a preinstalled application, you won't find it in the "Programs and Features" control panel to be removed. Instead, you have to use the Windows PowerShell to remove it. Use the following procedure:

1. Click in the search box in your Taskbar and type `powershell`; select "Windows Powershell" (not "Windows Powershell ISE" if that shows up).
2. At the prompt, type `Get-AppxPackage -Name king.com.CandyCrushSaga` and press Enter (TIP: to copy/paste that command, copy as usual, then just right-click in the PowerShell window to paste).
3. Look for the "PackageFullName" line in the result that comes up; it should be something similar to `king.com.CandyCrushSaga_1.540.1.0_x86__khqwnzmzfus32`.
4. Copy the PackageFullName by left-clicking and dragging to highlight it, then right-click in the PowerShell window to copy the selected text.
5. Type `Remove-AppxPackage` (include trailing space) and paste the PackageFullName that you copied in step 4, then press Enter.
6. A teal-colored text dialog should come up showing the removal process, and then uninstall should be complete.
7. Repeat step 2 to verify that it uninstalled successfully (the command should now return nothing).
8. Lastly, confirm that Candy Crush Saga is no longer in your Start Menu.
9. Enjoy a Candy-Crush-Free computer!

Source: Adapted from [GHacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/08/02/how-to-remove-core-apps-in-windows-10/) article on removing core apps from Windows 10

Comment: I wrote this specifically because I had a hard time finding how to uninstall the game when I was searching including the term "Candy Crush Saga". Hopefully this question will show up in results for future users wanting to remove it :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the "turn windows features on/off" area of programs?

Comment: @Raystafarian, in a perfect world, operating systems wouldn't come with bloatware, and it shouldn't come preinstalled at all.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I meant, I don't have W10 available, but I don't see why it wouldn't be there, like regular games in other versions of windows..

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home Premium. I was able to uninstall it from the installed programs list. I clicked on Candy Crush and the uninstall button appeared. It uninstalled like any other added program.

Comment: One thing that I can see here..  There is nothing to prevent re-installation of Candy Crush and or other apps.  Sounds like a good place for a GPO/LGPO, yes I know it sounds like a workplace situation, but would be good for the home user that does not want these apps as well.

Comment: Does PowerShell not allow you to do something along the lines of `Get-AppxPackage -Name king.com.CandyCrushSaga | Remove-AppxPackage` ?

Comment: I just noticed by accident in ProcessMonitor  that Candy Crush Saga was updated in "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga_1.85.500.0_x86(...)". The folder size is about 121 MB. But the program was deinstalled correctly in Powershell, i.e. the result of `Get-AppxPackage *Candy*`is empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 14):

First of all *Candy Crush Saga* is not a **desktop** program. So you can't find it "Programs and Features". It's an **app** just like in your mobile phone.

To remove the app,

- You can just search for *Candy Crush Saga* (or just "ca" does the trick), right click on the app result and then click uninstall.

[image: setp1]

- Or if *Candy Crush Saga* is pinned to start menu(usually it is) just right click and then click uninstall.

[image: setp2]

alternatively you can use the Windows Store or Powershell to remove the app.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers point to the package name `king.com.CandyCrushSaga`, on latest Windows 10 Pro it is `king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga`.

Regardless of the full name, run PowerShell as an administrator and execute:

```
Get-AppxPackage *CandyCrush* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

<sup>I'm not sure why this [complicated answer](https://superuser.com/a/958563/493903) was posted, but manual copy-paste steps are not required here.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Removal form Start menu or the `Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage` command only removes applications for the current user, but sometimes keeps them on disk.

Full removal requires specifying the `-AllUsers` switch and running the command as the `SYSTEM` user.

1. Download and extract the [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) utility.
2. Run `PsExec.exe -isd PowerShell.exe`.
3. In the new PowerShell window run `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers 'king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga' | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`

You might also want do remove other 3rd-party games bundled with Windows:

- king.com.BubbleWitch3Saga
- A278AB0D.DisneyMagicKingdoms
- A278AB0D.MarchofEmpires

Comment: I am not sure why this was marked down as it is more correct.  The -AllUsers flag is necessary to root all copies of the damn crapware foisted on us by Microsoft.  PsExec.exe is not necessary though, just a powershell session run as Administrator

Answer (score 2):

### *// In Windows 10 v1607, this is no longer working*

[A better way is to disable the install during Windows 10 install](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/11/23/seeing-extra-apps-turn-them-off/). Create an `unattend.xml` add this a add a `RunSynchronous` command to set the registry value `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures` under `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent` to `1`.

```
<RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Description>disable consumer features</Description>
    <Order>5</Order>
    <Path>reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent /v DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
</RunSynchronousCommand>
```

Or [import this registry (.reg) file:](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/165029-how-get-rid-candy-crush-soda-saga-other-windows-10-start-menu-junk-good.html)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent]
"DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures"=dword:00000001
```

Before it looks like this:

[image]

Now start menu is much cleaner:

[image]

Comment: The same thing can be achieved by using regedit to alter or create the DWORD key named `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent` to a value of `1` and then restarting windows.

Comment: @Toby this is what my comamnd does, but this no longer works in 1607, only for Enterprise/Education

Comment: Yep, just making it explicit for people that didn't want to add a file. did not realise it has changed under 1607 :(+

Answer (score 0):

1. Unpin from start menu (if you never left clicked on it like me, it may be just an "ad" - so not installed yet)
   [image: unpin]
2. If it was started/installed already (alternative to PowerShell): remove per machine with 1 MB program O&O [AppBuster](https://www.oo-software.com/en/ooappbuster)
   [image: remove per machine]

Answer (score -4):

Windows 10 upgrade does appear include candy crush. I have a work machine that was game free and after upgrade found ccs installed. I cannot say 100% sure but it was definitely not in the start menu until after the upgrade. Uninstalling deletes it but you still need to go to regedit and click find and input candy and you will find a number of instances and keys. Delete them, don't worry it will not cause any problems as long as they say candy crush.

Comment: doesn't answer the question correctly, especially on machines with multiple logins.