# Windows 10 on Surface Pro 4 Candy Crush Soda Saga will not uninstall from start list

Tags: windows-10

I uninstalled Candy Crush Saga and Candy Crush Soda Saga from control panel.  Then I went to regedit and deleted both under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  I went to Windows PowerShell and the program is not there.  The Candy Crush Soda Saga App is still showing up on my desktop list. I right click and choose Don't show on list, but nothing happens.  The program does not open if I click on the app.  What else can I do?  The reason I want to remove all of it is because this past update was causing critical issues.

Answer (score -1):

There is already a very comprehensive solved/closed Super User question regarding this specific subject:

[How do I remove Candy Crush Saga from Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10)

It may be wise to utilize a previous System Restore point to a time prior to your problematic changes, and then implement the instructions I referenced above.

Comment: The proper thing to do, when you have identified an answer to an existing question, that answers another question is to flag the question without an answer as a duplicate of the question with an answer

Comment: My apologies, and thanks for educating me a bit more.