# Why is my shovelware reinstalling?

Tags: windows-10

I picked up a Win10 Pro machine for my mother.   While I'm not new to Windows, I expected some shovelware, but I'm new to Windows 10.

I right-click, uninstalled March of Empires, Minecraft, Candy Crush Soda Saga, Bubble Witch 3 Saga.   A few minutes later, they reinstalled themselves.

I read a forum post which said that updates in-the-pipe may have caused the apps to reinstall.   So I uninstalled them again.   They seemed gone.   This post [How do I remove Candy Crush Saga from Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10) seems to agree, right-click, uninstall.

I completed setting up the machine for my mother, a few maintinence reboots and the regular Windows updates were finished...

Yet they reinstalled a third time.

What am I missing here?  Has Microsoft lost their mind?  Did I miss a "don't reinstall" option when uninstalling?

[image]

What's the *right* way to get rid of this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/942419/11574

Answer (score 1):

[First google search result:](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/13501-how-do-u-keep-win-10-reinstalling-apps-i-removed-privacy.html)

> Open Powershell and type: Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
>
> To uninstall an app type: Remove-AppxPackage PackageFullName

I suspect it's because you deleted these apps from the current account only.

Comment: If your only research is the first google hit, you're not sure why the apps came back when uninstalled, and your only insight as to why this is like this is "you agree", I don't understand why you posted.   The link I posted has similar advice as your first-google-search-result, but it doesn't address "What is the right way to get rid of this" nor why it is like this.

Comment: Did you try this and the apps still got reinstalled?

Comment: I posted "first google hit only" to demonstrate little research effort on your part. When you do the same thing three times, you get the same result three times.

Comment: You really need to read my question.

Comment: Regarding "Why is this happening", search about [Dark patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern) (closely related). The fact that it's Microsoft doesn't change anything - remember those forced upgrades to Windows 10.