# Windows App continues to install updates even after uninstalled. How to remove it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, adware, bloatware

My computer ran out of storage space so I analyzed what was taking up my disk space. I noticed [Candy Crush Saga taking up multiple gigabytes of space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhKE.png) even though I remember uninstalling it a long time ago using the [steps found on another post](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10?newreg=06e6c13e31da485eb14f8ff441ce4aca). When I try to delete the Candy Crush Saga items using power shell, powershell is unable to find the app. And when I try to view or delete the folders found with TreeSize, I am denied permission.

How can I **fully remove** this app and stop its continuous updates that are eating more and more of my hard drive space?

[Attempts at locating app via powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLM5V.png)

Comment: I suspect you are getting inaccurate information from TreeSize.  Did you change the permissions on WindowsApps, by default neither a User nor Administrator, has the permissions to view the contents of directory contained within it.

Comment: (1) The linked question has more than six answers.  Please describe what you tried and what happened.   (2) Please post text as text, not screenshots.