# Deleting windows native games

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Using windows 10 ive found several game related folders in WindowsApps folder. They came with windows. For example candy crush and something about a magic castle. They take up a lot of GB. Ive managed to uninstall a Candy Crush app but that was just 200mb and there are a lot of heavey CC folders left. Ive given myself ownership and full privileges over this folder still i cant delete the folders. It says i need permission from my own user, that i am actually loged in as.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove Candy Crush Saga from Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10).

Comment: However, what applications are you attempting to remove is an important detail you failed to provide, only certain applications can actually be removed by simply uninstalling them.  However, all the default games on (1803, 1809, and 1903) can be uninstalled.  The point of the duplicate flag is to highlight the fact, in order to uninstall any of the games installed, can be uninstalled by right click operation.  Taking ownership fo the WindowsApps directory is the incorrect method of uninstalling UWP applications.  *Uninstalling UWP applications will result in the application being removed.*