# How to remove Candycrushsaga folders from my windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I've uninstalled candycrush saga from my machine using the suggestions given on [here](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20the%20app%2C,result%20and%20then%20click%20uninstall.). and can confirm that it doesnt show up on my list of programs however, when I use win-dir-stat to figure out what's taking up space on my SSD I notice that there are still king.com.candycrushsaga folders on my pc that are taking up 20gb of space. Deleting them doesnt work because it says I require permission from SYSTEM and when I try to change the owner to my username and change the permissions on these folders to full control, I get a popup saying I need permission from my username even though thats the username I'm trying to use to delet the folders. Screenshot of the candycrush saga folders below:
[image]

Comment: You would have to forcefully take ownership of those folders in order to delete them  This can easily be done with WinZip or a similar program.  **I very much doubt WinDirStat is properly reporting the usage of those folders.**  Can you provide a different screenshot that shows the file name and extension of the files you believe is taking your disk space?  Simply uninstall Candy Crash should free up the space.  The answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10) will help you identify the one folder that is currently being used.

Comment: You might try some apps to delete them, e.g. https://techviral.net/software-to-force-delete-undeletable-files/, or use PowerRun to increase privileges, https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-4-run-with-highest-privileges/

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, one can boot to a Linux Live CD and delete files without problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I took ownership of the entire folder then used icacls to add full control permissions to the over 1000 folders that had been created and then deleted.