# Can't Remove Cortana from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, cortana

I tried following [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10/942419#942419), but I keep getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Download the tool called [win6x_registry_tweak](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/). Now open a [command prompt with admin rights](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) in the folder of the downloaded exe and run this command:

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-Cortana /r
```

This command removes the 3 cortana packages (Cortana main package, language pack and PAL package).

After a reboot your Windows is cortana free and **can't be reinstalled**!

Comment: "Now open a command prompt with admin rights in the folder of the downloaded exe and run this command" How do I open an admin command prompt inside a folder? I can only figure out how to open a normal command prompt. (I get this when I run it in a normal prompt: http://i.imgur.com/htxleRy.png)

Comment: Nevermind figured it out: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/47415-open-command-window-here-administrator.html

Comment: This fix breaks the search function.

Comment: Try use StartIsBack: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557 It is much better compared to the crappy/slow default thing in Win10

Comment: StartIsBack works! Is there a list of other Win10 app names (like "Microsoft-Windows-Cortana") to use with win6x_registry_tweak?

Comment: run **install_wim_tweak.exe /o /l** to dump all packages into a text file. With the tool you can also remove other crap like Defender or the Flash Player from Windows. But be careful what you remove!!!!

Comment: And can this be done without using comandline? I mean some GUI solution.

Comment: @convert use StartIsBack to get the old Win7 startmenu and here you can uninstall apps via UI

Comment: @magicandre1981 Is there a link to that StartIsBack?

Comment: @convert http://startisback.com/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Does it also make my Win 10 look like good old Win 7?

Comment: @convert yes, you can select the Win7 theme to get Win7 style startmenu and taskbar