# How to prevent Windows Update from reinstalling bloatware?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bloatware

Apparently sometimes a Windows Update includes reinstalling Bloatware such as Candy Crush Saga. Is there any way to *prevent* this from happening instead of having to manually remove everything again and again and again...?

Comment: The only official solution is to use a version of Windows 10 that does not include it, ( i.e. Windows 10 Enterprise, or Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB).  Outside of that, you can remove it these packages from the .wim file, but difficult to do with an existing system.  [Key step is to remove the program for all users.](https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: And Enterprise version isn't completely free of bloatware either

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, that post seems to also prevent reinstallation via `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage`

Comment: @pun True, I noticed some gaming related stuff at work. Does not sound very Enterprise-y to me...

Comment: @pun - You can configure Enterprise, defer the feature updates, or use the current LTSB based on 1607.

Comment: Either way sounds like lots of effort to get rid of things never asked for...

Comment: Note to self: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-remove-bloatware-windows-10/

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - Like I said you can create your own .wim file if you want, Windows has had things automatically installed for years, doesn't anyone remember Solitaire?

Comment: @Ramhound Solitaire was actually usefull  No, seriously, at least in the old days once uninstalled (or removed from my unattended install CD) it _remained_ uninstalled and didn't come back via updates... But you're right, I guess I'll have to bother creating a .wim someday

Comment: Part of the problem is windows is set to reset it self back to original configuration state meaning it always has those files so it can go back to day one.  Uninstalled is really just disabled these days with win 10.  I have used "decrapifier v2" from spiceworks.  https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3977-windows-10-decrapifier-version-2

Comment: @Damon Sounds promising, I'll have a look at it, thanks!