# Stop Candy Crush (and other bloatware) from automatically installing every time I start my system

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

I recently installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creator's Update) on my MacBook Pro 2016. Of course it has to come with some bloatware that I don't need such as Candy Crush. Before on my older MacBook Pro with 1703 installed I can just uninstall them and forget about it. But on this new version, I can uninstall it just fine. But every time I starts Windows, the app just got automatically placed back. Any solution to this?

Comment: try this: https://winaero.com/blog/a-tweak-to-turn-off-automatically-installing-suggested-apps-in-windows-10/

Comment: Similar SU discussion here: https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10

Answer (score 3):

The following forum threads may be of assistance.

This forum thread, https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10/issues/77 contains a suggestion on turning off Microsoft Consumer Experiences which appears to be turned off for some versions of Windows 10.

Supposedly you can prevent apps from reinstalling by enabling the group policy: Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Cloud Content | Enable: Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences.

> So far I've not been hit with more bloatware. However when doing MS
>   Updates some of Microsoft base apps will still come back. Third party
>   apps like Candy Crush or other BS doesn't seem to auto-download.

This article, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-installing-apps-like/a8e6fcaf-8890-4c11-b944-c6d1adc9be09?auth=1 says:

> lacrumb replied on  February 21, 2017 Right click on the tile, If
>   uninstall does not show click on More. . As things progress the
>   Insider updates mo longer install those that you have uninstalled. In
>   April when the big update takes place you will not have the problem.

This article, https://www.pcauthority.com.au/feature/how-to-stop-annoying-programs-reinstalling-474992 as well as several others indicate you need to use Powershell to uninstall Candy Crush and the other annoying game apps as Windows 10 thinks they are necessary apps due to marketing arrangements.

> A better option is to delete the app's package from the operating
>   system, to stop it boomeranging back (you can reinstall it manually if
>   you choose). Type PowerShell into the search box and press Enter to
>   run the command. When Windows PowerShell opens, type the command
>   Get-AppxPackage to see all the apps you have installed. Locate the app
>   you want to banish permanently and note or copy its package name – for
>   example 'king.com.CandyCrushSaga_1.93.1400.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32'. Type
>   the command Remove-AppxPackage followed by the package name, and press
>   Enter to get rid of the app for good.